# Need a seminal reference

Tags: multivariate-analysis, references, t-distribution

Does anyone know of the seminal reference for the multivariate $\mathcal{T}$ process?

The oldest reference to it I can find is

*Gamerman 1997: Markov Chain Monte Carlo: Stochastic Simulation for Bayesian Inference.*

Comment: Out of interest, what reference did you use in the end?

Answer (score 1):

I'ld try going through the document you mentioned yourself and see whether there's any further references in there. There's a mention of Odell and Feiveson (1966) "A numerical procedure to generate a sample covariance matrix" (page 25) in the multivariate student T distribution section starting on page 24. Not sure, but maybe that helps?

Answer (score 1):

Kelker, 1970?  (See introduction of http://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/12009314.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this is what you are after but here goes anyway https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotelling%27s_T-squared_distribution

Comment: The multivariate T *process* is a multivariate stochastic process whose finite marginals are Multivariate T.  All the references point to Gamerman (1997).  I'm pretty sure Hotelling did not contemplate this process as such.  The key issue concerns what autocovariance functions arise from such processes.